# How can i check boxes from simple_list_item_multiple_choice via retrieving data from a sharedPreferences?

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

i'm pretty new to android-development and im trying to build a ListView with 8 items, that each have checkboxes. is set them up already, but i dont know how i can set one/several box beeing checked via retrieving key.value-pairs from a SharedPreferences.

i think im pretty close, but there is one or two lines of code missing :(

this my code in the onCreate-method:

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);

getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("Spiel4", "yes").commit();

lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, lvItems));
lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    for (int i=1;i<9;i++) {
        tmpString = null;
        tmpString = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getString("Spiel"+i,"");

        if (tmpString.equals("yes")) {
            // -----> MISSING LINE HERE <-----
            Log.i(tag,"Spiel"+i+"-value is YES!");
        }

    }
```

p.s.: my first post, formatting tricked me :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use

```
lv.setItemChecked(i, true);
```

add this line on missing line :)

Comment: thx man, that is exactly what im looking.  had to adjust it to i-1 to relate to the proper row though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the PrefenceActivity or PreferenceFragement?
Take a look at:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Another option is write your own Adapter, that is not hard too. Look that:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_custom